# Modify custom field input data before creating a new post

Tags: php, functions, customization, hooks, actions

I'm try to check input data before it is added to DB.
For example:

I have a custom post meta named `book_isbn` in post page. I want to make sure that this variable `$_POST['book_isbn']` is valid before it is added to DB.

So far I know that I can use hook `wp_insert_post_data` to achieve this. I'm not sure if I did this right. It doesn't work for me. Please check the code below.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'clean_data_before_post_created', '99', 2 );

    function clean_data_before_ad_created( $data , $postarr ) {
          $data['book_isbn'] = clean_isbn($_POST['book_isbn']);
          return $data;
     }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs your function right after the post has been saved (created/updated):

```
add_action('save_post','clean_data_while_saving_post',1);

function clean_data_while_saving_post($post_id) {
  $data = get_post_meta($post_id,'book_isbn',true);
  update_post_meta($post_id,'book_isbn',clean_isbn($data));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work either. And your filter missing the last parameter.

Comment: Does this really have to happen before the post is created, or could this also be done right after (while) the post is created?

Comment: This must be happened before the post is inserted into database.

Comment: May I ask how the custom post meta `book_isbn` is added to the post? Is it done via the "Custom Field" box, or via a plugin/theme option? Also, I changed my answer, would that work for you?

Comment: This doesn't work because at this point, there is no saved data in DB so you can't call get_post_meta to retrieve the meta_value.

Comment: I beg to differ, `save_post` provides a post ID, please give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35832/discussion-between-johano-fierra-and-louis-tran).